# Code folding with Emacs ESS, polymode for a knitr file (RNW)

Tags: emacs, r, code-folding

Is there anyway of using code folding in an RNW knitr file that contains R and latex code? In particular to be able to fold the R code chunks. I am using polymode so as this changes the mode as you navigate in and out of chunks, this interferes with standard solutions for code folding.

About all I can find for this particular situation is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354137/emacs-folding-unfolding-r-code) on stackoverflow, but it is now quite old. Is there any improvements on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yafolding may be able to handle this  https://github.com/zenozeng/yafolding.el    but I don't have a working/detailed setup/config example yet.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try this out and get back with my findings.